# Problema SCSS / CSS

Tags: css, css3, scss

Hasta hace poco usaba mi hoja de estilos SCSS, hacía las modificaciones y todo funcionaba bien, se me añadían a mi hoja de estilos CSS. Pero desde está tarde aplico cambios en mi SCSS y no se añaden. Sin embargo, si modifico mi hoja CSS, se me siguen añadiendo de nuevo perfectamente.

**¿Qué ha podido pasar?**
He estado mirando y no veo código de errores por ningún lado.

Nota: compilé con koala.

```css
@font-face {
      font-family: 'webfontregular';
      src: url("../fonts/waterlily-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/waterlily-webfont.woff") format("woff");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal; }
    html {
      font-size: 15px; }
    
    /*Estilos bloque bienvenidos*/
    .bienvenidos {
      background-color: blueviolet;
      background-size: cover;
      overflow: hidden; }
    
    .logobrand {
      width: 35px; }
    
    .boton3rayas {
      margin-top: 0.3rem; }
    
    .navbar-fixed-top {
      background: #b5a7dc; }
    
    .navbar-light .navbar-brand {
      color: #fdfb8e;
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      text-transform: uppercase; }
    
    .navbar-toggler {
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      color: #fdfb8e; }
    
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
      color: #fdfb8e;
      text-align: center; }
    
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
      background: #8a2be2; }
    
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
      color: #fdfb8e; }
    
    #menuprincipal {
      clear: both; }
    
    .texto-bienvenido {
      color: yellow;
      margin-top: 7rem;
      font-family: "webfontregular", Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 2rem; }
    
    .bienvenido2 p {
        color: black; }
    
    .imaginarq {
      font-size: 4rem; }
    
    .bienvenido2 {
      color: yellow; }
    
    /*Estilos bloque quehacemos*/
    .quehacemos {
      background-color: #fdfb8e; }
    
    .quehacemos h4 {
        font-weight: bolder; }
    
    .quehacemos .fa {
      font-size: 3rem;
      background-color: #fdfb8e; }
    
    .quehacemos .fa {
      font-size: 3rem;
      color: blueviolet; }
    
    /*Estilos quienes somos*/
    .quienes {
        background-color: #eee; }
    
    .conchi {
      border-radius: 50%; }
    
    .cabeza {
      border-radius: 50%; }
    
    .agustin {
      border-radius: 50%; }
    
    .somosbotones {
        font-size: 1.7rem;
        color: blueviolet;
    }
    /*Estilos footer*/
    .footer {
      background-color: cadetblue; }
    
    .footer .fa {
      font-size: 35px; }
    
    /*Estilos Media Query*/
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      #menuprincipal {
        clear: inherit; } }
    
    /*# sourceMappingURL=estilos.css.map */
```

Comment: Puede pasar si hace falta un ; o si falta cerrar una clase css con }

Comment: subo el codigo sccc, te haria falta tb el html no no??

Comment: El código que has subido es válido, compila sin problemas. Deberías revisar la configuración de Koala; el error debe estar por allí.

Comment: lo hice con scout tambien pero nada, sigue el mismo problema tengo que editar el css como edite el sccs no me realiza ningun cambio.

Comment: El código que has puesto **es válido**. Tienes que verificar que tu **watcher** esté **observando cambios** en los archivos `scss`. Si no te está compilando, el error es que **no se está observando los cambios**.

Comment: Por la sintaxis y el comentario del final de tu código: `/*# sourceMappingURL=estilos.css.map */` ese debe ser el código generado y no el SCSS. Deberías poner el código antes de compilar para poder saber si el problema está ahí o es otra cosa

Comment: El código parece correcto. Yo para usar LESS hago uso del editor de texto Brackets. Puedes buscar en él plugins para el nodejs y el compilador de LESS/SASS, y si hay algún error, te lo notifica (si es un error de sintaxis te indica la línea, o si hay algo abierto te dice que algo está mal).

Answer (score 0):

Si koala no te esta emitiendo ningún mensaje de error es posible que por algún cambio en la configuración o alguna otra situación este guardando el archivo compilado en una ubicación diferente y ya no esta reescribiendo el archivo que realmente esta ligado a tu html.

Verifica el nombre y ruta del css que esta generando koala y asegúrate de que ese sea el que estas cargando.